# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addTopic' of undefined. Am I blind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

since I've been staring at this problem for some days now, I'm kinda new at AngularJS, I thought maybe someone here could help me. So to my problem:

I get a Typeerror when i try to save a new topic on a forum I'm creating: My controller

```
module.controller('newTopicController', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataService', function ($scope, $http, $window, dataService) {
$scope.newTopic = {};

$scope.save = function () {

    dataService.addTopic($scope.newTopic)
    .then(function () {
        $window.location = "/#";
    },
    function () {
        alert("couldnt save topic");
    });
};
}]);
```

And my factory:

```
module.factory("dataService", function ($http, $q) {

var _topics = [];
var _isInit = false;

var _isReady = function () {
    return _isInit;
};

var _getTopics = function () {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("/api/topics?withReplies=true")
    .then(function (result) {
        angular.copy(result.data, _topics);
        _isInit = true;
        deferred.resolve();
    },
    function () {
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

var _addTopic = function (newTopic) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post("/api/topics", newTopic)
   .then(function (result) {
       var createdTopic = result.data;
       _topics.splice(0, 0, createdTopic);
       deferred.resolve(createdTopic);
   },
   function () {
       deferred.reject();
   });

    return deferred.promise;
};

return {
    topics: _topics,
    getTopics: _getTopics,
    addTopic: _addTopic,
    isReady: _isReady
};
});
```

So when i try to add a topic to the forum I just get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addTopic' of undefined" in the controller, right where dataService.addTopic($scope.newTopic) is.

I also have another controller who also uses the factory, but that shouldnt be a problem right?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: this is because your injection is wrong. correct the order of injections like ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'dataService', function ($scope, $http, $window, dataService)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems incorrect:

```
module.controller('newTopicController', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataService', function ($scope, $http, $window, dataService) {...}
```

Change it to:

```
module.controller('newTopicController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'dataService', function ($scope, $http, $window, dataService) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I really am blind :P